# Google Drive API for iOS code-signing error on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, google-drive-api

I am using iOS-9.2.1, Xcode-7.2.1:
Following step-by-step Google's "Drive API for iOS"-example (shown [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift) ...under Swift) - I keep getting the following error after completion of all steps :

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 9.2'

The XCode-Simulator works fine. But the above error only happens when trying to get it to run on the physical iPhone.

What are the exact steps to get the Google-Drive API running under iOS and on the actual iPhone - not just on simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution...

The [step-by-step creation of the Google-Drive API in Swift](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift) does not explain how to code-sing the 3rd-party Google-Framework (GTL.framework) under iOS inside Xcode.

First of all, do not confuse your App code-signing (project and target) with the  additionally needed code-signing of your 3rd party GTL.framework.

The way to proceed:

- select GTLCore project
- under "General" tab, select Team = None
  (here is the catch: even tough the setting Team=None was already set, by selecting it again (=None), there is a hidden change in code-signing settings happening. Frankly, this is not obvious !)

[image]

- to check that there is a change: go to Build Settings --> Code Signing Identity and verify that your Code-Signing is well set to "iOS Developer".
  Again, not only for your project and target but most importantly also for your GTLiOSCore framework !!

[image]

After that, the code-signing error dissappears...